How can I fix debugging error in Code::Blocks which uses MSYS2?
I installed gnu GCC and GDB with MSYS2.
This is the command I used:
pacman -Syu
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain

I added environment variable "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin" and I changed the compiler location in Code::Blocks.
It works well in "compile & run", but when I'm debugging, at the last line of the main function, it shows this error:

C:\M\B\mingw-w64\crt\crt.exe.c not found

I tried other MinGW versions, such as 8.1.0, and it worked out well. I also tried Cygwin, but it started debugging and finished.

I use MSys2 and I have used Code::Blocks -- but no long do. While CB is a good tool, it is quite dated. MSys2 provides very good terminals in which you can run gdb manually for small projects. For larger projects, I've become a fan of VSCode (or vscodium) as an IDE. Yes, like all IDEs it has a learning curve, but the MS documentation is quite good -- even for Linux use. Your install looks fine, the -toolchain package is just a meta-package that installs a number of gcc utilities (including gdb), the C:\M\B\mingw-w64 error doesn't match your "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin" path - double-check

That's normal behavior. You're trying to debug beyond main(), so it tries to open crtexe.c which is where main was called from. Why is that a problem?

Open Code::Blocks
Configure debugger

In the top menu go to Settings and select Debugger...
In the left pane select GDB/CDB debugger
Select the desired config on the left
Set the location of bin\gdb.exe

Configure compiler to use the debugger

In the top menu go to Settings and select Compiler...
Under Selected compiler choose GNU GCC Compiler
Click the tab Toolchain executables
Set Debugger to the config you configured above


Thank you for your answer,but I did tried both of it.

Full instruction is at https://winlibs.com/#usage-codeblocks if you are willing to try the winlibs standalone build instead of MSYS2.
